# Leibniz Rule, FCT and Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, integration

a) Let $\displaystyle x(t)=\int_0^te^{t-s}f(s)\,ds$. Use the chain rule, Leibniz’s rule and the FCT to show that

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}-x(t)=f(t).$$

Check your result by observing that $\displaystyle x(t)=e^t\int_0^te^{-s}\,ds$.

b) Repeat this with $\displaystyle x(t)=\int_0^te^{t-s}\sin(t-s)f(s)\,ds$ to verify that

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}-2\dfrac{dx}{dt}+2x=f(t).$$

I would appreciate help for both parts, my approach was to differentiate both sides of the x(t) equation w.r.t. and then use Leibniz but I can’t seem to do anything more.

Comment: This is blatantly homework question, there's nothing tough that you can't solve....

Comment: Well I’ve tried for a while and I can’t solve it so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $H(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\:\text{d}t,$ then $H'(x)=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$

For the first case, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\frac{\text{d} x(t)}{\text{d}t} & =\frac{\text{d} e^t}{\text{d}t}\int_{0}^{t} e^{-s}f(s)\:\text{d}s + e^{t}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left\{\int_{0}^{t} e^{-s}f(s)\:\text{d}s\right\} \\
& =e^t\int_{0}^{t} e^{-s}f(s)\:\text{d}s + e^{t}\left\{\left. e^{-s}f(s)\right|_{s=t} -0\right\} \\
& =\int_{0}^{t} e^{t-s}f(s)\:\text{d}s + e^{t}[ e^{-t}f(t)]  \\
& =x(t) + e^{t-t}f(t) \\
& =x(t) + f(t)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
The next case is totally analogous.

Comment: Thank you so much!